# Group and count in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this bit of code and I get an empty object.

```
@results = PollRoles.find(
            :all, 
            :select => 'option_id, count(*) count', 
            :group => 'option_id', 
            :conditions => ["poll_id = ?", @poll.id])
```

Is this the correct way of writing the query? I want a collection of records that have an option id and the number of times that option id is found in the PollRoles model.

**EDIT:** This is how I''m iterating through the results:

```
<% @results.each do |result| %>
            <% @option = Option.find_by_id(result.option_id) %>
            <%= @option.question %> <%= result.count %>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: How does a PollRole relate to an Option?  Why do you print a new `question` for each `Option`?  Wouldn't many `Options` relate to the same question?  Showing the basic `has_many`, `belongs_to` declarations and adding a bit more explanation of the problem you are trying to solve would help me in trying to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [this function](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M002130) to do things like this
`PollRoles.count(:all, :group => 'option_id')` should return a hash mapping every `option_id` with the number of records that matched it.

Comment: I changed it to this:
@results = PollRoles.count(:all, :group => 'option_id', :conditions => ["poll_id = ?", @poll.id])

but still get a nil result.

Comment: im confused.. u say want 'a collection of records that have an option id', but ur condition is :conditions => ["poll_id = ?", @poll.id]).. are option id's and poll id's the same.. could you explain the structure of your db a little better

Comment: options are related to a poll. A poll has many options. So here I'm obviously trying to display the results for a certain poll.

Answer (score 0):

What do you get with this:

PollRoles.find(:all,:conditions=>["poll_id = ?",@poll.id]).collect{|p| p.option_id}

Comment: then you have no PollRoles with poll_id == @poll.id

Comment: OK I am getting results actually. But how do I iterate through them? See edited code.

Comment: you shouldn't be searching in your view, you want to collect all the data in your controller: @results = PollRoles.count(:all, :group => 'option_id', :conditions => ["poll_id =?",@poll.id]).collect{|option_id,count| [Option.find(option_id),count]} then in your view: <% @results.each do |option,count| %> <%= option.question %> <%= count %> <% end %>